# Firefox gets stuck at XWayland

Tags: gnome, firefox, wayland

I am running GNOME 44 on Wayland (Arch Linux), and I would like Firefox to run in Wayland mode as well.

Unfortunately, it is getting stuck in XWayland. I followed the steps mentioned in Archwiki **[1]**, but I had no luck.

The `about:support` page still shows XWayland as the Window Protocol.

**UPDATE:**
Following @Artem advices, if I launch `firefox` from terminal it starts correctly in Wayland mode;
but when I launch it from gnome-shell, I get the afore-mentioned problem;
I've already set up the `MOZ_ENABLE_WAYLAND` environment variable via `.bashrc`, infact

```
echo $MOZ_ENABLE_WAYLAND
1
```

but it seems ignored when launching Firefox from UI

---

**[1]** https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Firefox#Wayland

Comment: Have you actually exited all the running instances? Please open a terminal and type `ps ax | grep firefox` - you should see nothing but grep itself. Now in the same terminal type `MOZ_ENABLE_WAYLAND=1 firefox` - this should absolutely force Firefox to run in native Wayland mode. If it's still doesn't work though it's hard to believe, probably your Firefox was built without Wayland support. You didn't specify where you got it.

Comment: updated OP with a more detailed issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I've already set up the `MOZ_ENABLE_WAYLAND` environment variable via `.bashrc`, infact

It's not necessarily read and used for your Gnome/Wayland sessions.

You could simply create a launcher or bash script which does the necessary stuff.

You could also consult with https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Environment_variables

Comment: could you expand/clarify your statement "It's not necessarily read and used for your Gnome/Wayland sessions"; I have a plethora of variables in .bashrc and I have never had a such kind of problem!

Comment: @mattia.b89 *I have a plethora of variables in .bashrc and I have never had a such kind of problem!* yeah, because you use BASH. Your desktop application, whatever that is, is **not** BASH. It doesn't read or care about your `.bashrc`. Imagine you used ZSH or KSH. Would you also be surprised your desktop application doesn't import zsh/ksh exported environment variables?

Comment: I have fixed the issue by moving `MOZ_ENABLE_WAYLAND` variable into a .conf file under `~/.config/environment.d/`

Comment: Great! This will also apply to Thunderbird.